# what will i need to create a website with a chatroom?

Tags: web

i want create a website for employees that does the following....
1) employee types in their name and it clocks them in
2) this will add them to a chatroom 
3) this will add them to a list of employees logged in
4) buttons for when they go on a break or lunch
5) we have a verbal queue when we call to a particular number...i would like to have this on this website
6) a sound that plays when somebody presses a persons name.. or for the queue or a sound that plays when somebody name is mentioned in the chatroom

im not really worried about security ..will be using this in a office..i made a website back in high school that was a long time ago...any ideas on what tools i need to create this website could help me out a lot

Comment: What you need is to hire a programmer. Never thought I'd be actively plugging [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

I will do it in Meteor, full stack javascript framework for real time appliaction. ( http://meteor.com/ )

then I will try some examples for chat app http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2013/07/17/tutorial-writing-your-first-metor-application/

Answer (score -2):

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) is a good starting point. Using node.js you can create exactly what you want.